# How can I drive an LP101WX2 LCD panel with the Chalkboard Electronics HDMI-dualLDVDS converter?

Tags: lcd, converter, display, hdmi, lvds

I am trying to drive an [LP101WX2](http://www.lcd-source.com/datasheet/LG+Display/LP101WX2-SLA1.pdf) panel with the [Chalkboard Electronics HDMI-dualLDVDS converter](https://chalk-elec.com/?p=2109) but all I am getting is a black screen.

I tried to flash the board's firmware with both the demo and the FullHD+ firmwares and it makes no difference. Also, I wrote the panel's EDID (from the datasheet) to the board but no dice. I also tried with the original EDID the converter came with. Again, no difference.

This is how I initially wired up the converter to the panel:

[image]

For now, I am controlling the backlight separately (VLED, GND, LED_ENABLE and LED_PWM) to ensure the converter isn't doing anything funky.

Since the panel is using just 4 twisted wire pairs I did some digging around and found out that the converter is using the [DS90C387A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ds90c387a.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-alldatasheets-df-pf-SEP-wwe) to drive the LVDS panels. I thought that maybe it's not working because the DS90C387A is set up to work in dual mode. According to the datasheet, pin 23, named DUAL, is responsible for configuring the mode:

> Three-mode select for dual pixel, single pixel, or single pixel input to dual
> pixel output operation. Single pixel mode when input is low (only LVDS
> channels A0 thru A3 and CLK1 are active) for power savings. Dual mode is
> active when input is high. Single in - dual out when input is at 1/2 Vcc. (Note
> 10)>[...]
>
> To configure for single pixel or dual pixel application using
> the DS90C387A/DS90CF388A, the “DUAL” pin must be set
> to Vcc (dual) or Gnd (single)

According to note 10, the DUAL pin has an internal pull down so all I had to do was ensure there was no pull-up resistor connected to the pin. According to the [converter's schematics](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7BWcJPjt1LNS1Y2elVpVklHMzQ/view?resourcekey=0-cg_lTOc2NSf1T39P-jbh3w), the DUAL pin is connected to VCC through the R17 resistor. After unsoldering it, the screen still did not show anything. No noise, no nothing. Just black.

After taking a closer look at the DS90C387A datasheet I noticed that the pinout shows that pins 50 through 38 are for the odd rows and pins 37 to 26 are for the even rows, excluding some VCC and GND pins. It is also mentioned that the even row pins are disabled in single mode.

According to both the converter's schematic and its support page, the even pins are connected to pins 5 to 16 of the converter's connector:

[image][image]

However, looking at the traces of the actual board, the connections seems to be the other way around. The odd pins are connected to the connectors 5-16 pins:
[image]

I don't know if I misunderstood something or if they truly mislabeled the pins but I went ahead and swapped around the pins in the connector housing like so:

[image]

Still, the image remained black.

I'm also not sure why the converter pins are labeled as RX. This implies that whatever connects to it should have a matching TX pin and that the converter is the receiving end. The LCD panel datasheet also marked the pins as RX. Are they both receiving?

Is there something I missed? Is the converter incompatible with the LCD panel? How should I proceed? Should I not at least get some random incoherent image instead of just black?

And if anyone is wondering why I am posting the question here instead of writing the support team an email, it's because I did drop them an email on the 24th of January. I am yet to receive a reply.

Comment: I'd start following the signal chain from the source and forwards. First off, does whatever HDMI source you are connecting to recognize the converter board so that it starts outputting any image on the HDMI? If not, the LVDS connection itself does not matter. The HDMI source will basically only look for Hot plug detect (HPD) and the EDID memory.

Comment: I would think that it does recognize it. For example, when I connect the converter with the right EDID, I only get a max resolution of 1280x800. If I write the original EDID and connect the board, I get a max resolution of 1920x1200. I also tried creating a custom resolution in windows and modified all the settings (horizontal front porch, sync, etc.) according to the panel's datasheet.

Comment: Okay, so then one can assume that something is outputted on the HDMI. Do you have access to an oscilloscope? Then you can check the LVDS clock line, if there is any clock output from the converter board.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't. It's on my wish list but I don't have one yet. Can I check with a multimeter? Is it safe to assume that if I get a solid 0v then there's nothing on that line?

Comment: The clock signal will probably be around 1.25 V even when not active. And when active, swing around that voltage. Not so easy to check with a multimeter unfortunately. Although you can check the clock signal from the TFP401A to the DS90C387A, that is TTL and should read 0V when inactive. You could also check the GPIO_RA5 signal so that it is high, otherwise both HDMI receiver and LVDS transmitter is powered down.

Comment: RA5 is used to control the backlight on and off, but as I've said in the question, I am controlling the backlight manually for now i.e. I am powering it for a separate USB power brick. The backlight lights up just fine. Also, the status LED that is supposed to light up when input signal is detected is also solid green when the HDMI is plugged in.

Comment: According to the schematics, GPIO_RA5 is connected to the PDO pin of TFP401A and PD# pin of DS90C387A. If it is pulled low, both these chips will be in low power mode and not do anything useful. The signal has to be high if you want any image.

Comment: Just checked and I am getting 3.32V on that pin.

Comment: CLK pin is showing 1.68V